# Negative Dimensions error when trying to Print Tensor value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I input an image to the first layer of a pre-trained CNN (conv1) that computes 2D-Convolution, followed by a RELU. I want to see the output of this (first) layer. The code I'm using is given below:

```
from numpy import *
import os
#from pylab import *
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import time
from scipy.misc import imread
from scipy.misc import imresize
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from scipy.ndimage import filters
import urllib
from numpy import random
import tensorflow as tf
from caffe_classes import class_names

train_x = zeros((1, 227,227,3)).astype(float32)
train_y = zeros((1, 1000))
xdim = train_x.shape[1:]
ydim = train_y.shape[1]

#Read Image, and change to BGR
im1 = (imread("dog2.png")[:,:,:3]).astype(float32)
im1 = im1 - mean(im1)
im1[:, :, 0], im1[:, :, 2] = im1[:, :, 2], im1[:, :, 0]

net_data = load(open("bvlc_alexnet.npy", "rb"), encoding="latin1").item()

def conv(input, kernel, biases, k_h, k_w, c_o, s_h, s_w,  padding="VALID", group=1):
    c_i = input.get_shape()[-1]
    assert c_i%group==0
    assert c_o%group==0
    convolve = lambda i, k: tf.nn.conv2d(i, k, [1, s_h, s_w, 1], padding=padding)

    if group==1:
         conv = convolve(input, kernel)
    else:
        input_groups =  tf.split(input, group, 3)   #tf.split(3, group, input)
        kernel_groups = tf.split(kernel, group, 3)  #tf.split(3, group, kernel) 
        output_groups = [convolve(i, k) for i,k in zip(input_groups, kernel_groups)]
        conv = tf.concat(output_groups, 3)          #tf.concat(3, output_groups)
    return  tf.reshape(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases), [-1]+conv.get_shape().as_list()[1:])

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None,) + xdim)

#conv1
#conv(11, 11, 96, 4, 4, padding='VALID', name='conv1')
k_h = 11; k_w = 11; c_o = 96; s_h = 4; s_w = 4
conv1W = tf.Variable(net_data["conv1"][0])
conv1b = tf.Variable(net_data["conv1"][1])
conv1_in = conv(x, conv1W, conv1b, k_h, k_w, c_o, s_h, s_w, padding="SAME", group=1)
conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1_in)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
output = sess.run(conv1, feed_dict = {x:[im1]})
```

I want to print the values stored in conv1, so I write:

```
test = tf.Print(conv1, [conv1])
sess.run(test)
```

However, I get the following error message upon running:

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1148] Invalid argument: Shape [-1,227,227,3] has negative dimensions
E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:644] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Shape [-1,227,227,3] has negative dimensions
[[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,227,227,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Using conv1.eval() also gives the same error message. I'm using Python 3.5.2. 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

When you run a session and request an output, you must supply a feed_dict with all placeholders on which that output is dependent. This needs to be done for every session run, since separate session runs can use different inputs (e.g., this is how you perform repeated inference using the same graph).

In this case, you are running the session on the tensor `test`, which depends on `conv1`, which in turn depends on the placeholder `x`.

Changing to `sess.run(test, feed_dict = {x:[im1]})` should fix your problem.

However, if all you want is to view the value of the tensor `conv1`, this is exactly the return value of the call to `sess.run(conv1)`, so you might not need `tf.Print` at all.